# NotificationListenerService not work with me android 7.0

Tags: java, android

I want to remove review SMS in
MainActivity:

```
 if(!isNotificationServiceEnabled()){
            enableNotificationListenerAlertDialog = buildNotificationServiceAlertDialog();
            enableNotificationListenerAlertDialog.show();
        }
```

and in service:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        cancelNotification(sbn.getPackageName(), sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());
    }
    else {
        cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
    }
}
```

with Android 4.4 review sms this clean when show,
android 7.0 review just show and dont clean
I want to remove review sms(in image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0k5r.png)

Comment: What error are you getting? Does this code work on other versions? Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: thank for your comment, with other android version, this just review in toolbar and clean after that